# Is it possible to capture the text output of an Android google-voice-typing from terminal?

Tags: android, debian, adb

Say i want to use the microphone of my smartphone to input text in my terminal, using the google voice2speech engine. How would i do ?

I would first listen to the output of `google-voice-typing`, (but how ?) and then redirect to `stdin`.

Is there a simple way with `adb` commands ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to

1. find the Google quick search box
2. click on the mic icon
3. prompt the user to say something
4. find the search results
5. print the text

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

helper = ViewClient.view_client_helper()

# mic in voice search widget
obj_ref = helper.until.find_object(body={
    'clazz': 'android.widget.ImageButton',
    'clickable': True,
    'desc': 'Voice Search'
})
response = helper.ui_device.wait(oid=obj_ref.oid)
helper.ui_object2.click(oid=response['oid'])
print('Speak now...')
helper.ui_device.wait_for_window_update()

# text in search results
obj_ref = helper.until.find_object(body={
    'res': 'com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/googleapp_srp_search_box_text',
    'clazz': 'android.widget.TextView'
})
response = helper.ui_device.wait(oid=obj_ref.oid)
print('Text:')
print(helper.ui_object2.get_text(oid=response['oid']).text)
```

The output would be like this

```
Speak now...
Text:
this is another example
```

Comment: i have this `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9987): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/uiDevice/dumpWindowHierarchy?format=JSON (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9c448d4a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: Follow these steps: https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public